# Images.xcassets Xcode 5.0.2: Image truncated

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, xcode5, xcasset

My app is totally ready for App Store except one issue:
When testing the app on iPhone4 the image and also the launch-image are truncated at the bottom.

In the Images.xcassets folder, I have this example of a image in a image view:

The box named 1x has an image with size 640x960px named laddapp_blue-1.png. 
The box named 2x has an image with size 640x1136px named laddapp_blue@2x.png. 
The box named R4 has an image with size 640x960px named laddapp_blue-1-1.png.

I have made them in Photoshop and saved them as png.
I don't know if the resolution was 72dpi when I saved them or 300.
Is that affecting the size showing?

I have in 'general' set that I use Images.xcassets so nothing wrong there.

Comment: Please be aware that you need [Xcode 5.1.1 to submit to the AppStore](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04252014a) Also supporting iPhone 6 might be a good idea if you are planning a release.

Comment: Thank you @rckoenes! Then I will download the 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the LaunchImage in the asset catalog.

[image: LaunchImage section asset catalog]

And select the the correct option in the Project General tab:
[image: Project settings launch images source]

Comment: Ok. It might be that it is working different in 5.1.1

Comment: There is not support for the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus in Xcode 5.1.1 You will need Xcode 6 with the iOS 8 SDK to support the iPhone 6 and 6 plus. For the rest it should just work as above, but you will be missing the 5.5 and 4.7 LaunchImage.

Comment: Ok.Thx. I just finished downloading 5.1.1 and I am in a hurry for AppStore today. I will make some addings to the app soon and then I will download Xcode6 and make images for iPhone6. Is it anything that can go wrong or any problems with Xcode6 as far as you know? Should I throw away the older Xcode 5.0.1  before open 5.1.1?

Comment: My suggestion is to rename xcode.app to xcode5.app and then install xcode 6. This way you can keep both version on you system.

Comment: I now use 5.1.1 :D      iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) is still truncating the image. I made the "1X" now with 72dpi and 320x480px. Is that wrong? Going crazy about this now… :)

Comment: What do you mean with truncating the image?

Comment: I mean that like 30% of the lower part of the image is not seen. I have a button there, and on 3.5 inch I don't see it and not on my devive iPhone4 eather. ???